# Error 403 in loading images on subdomain

Tags: javascript, apache

I am receiving a 403 Error when trying to view a site I have live on one of our company subdomains.

All the paths are relative paths to the containing folder and, the strange thing is, the resources are loaded perfectly fine on a folder on the website rather than the subdomain.

I have tried to CHMOD the folder to 777 to test if it was a restriction from that perspective, but that has unfortunately not made any difference.

I have run the `ls -la` command to list the owner of the directories within the subdomain, and this is what I got:

```
[user@server tools]$ ls -la
total 72
drwxrwxrwx 5 enablebusiness enablebusiness  4096 Dec 18 22:06 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 enablebusiness enablebusiness  4096 Nov  8 13:55 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enablebusiness enablebusiness     0 Dec 18 22:06 .htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enablebusiness enablebusiness  3091 Dec 18 22:06 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enablebusiness enablebusiness   569 Dec 18 22:06 lock.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enablebusiness enablebusiness 37475 Dec 18 22:06 logo.png
drwxrwxrwx 2 enablebusiness enablebusiness  4096 Dec 18 22:06 password-generator
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enablebusiness enablebusiness   782 Dec 18 22:06 tick.png
drwxrwxrwx 3 enablebusiness enablebusiness  4096 Dec 18 22:06 to-do
drwxrwxrwx 3 enablebusiness enablebusiness  4096 Nov  8 13:56 .well-known
```

[This is what the subdomain looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQmnX.png)

[This is what the folder looks like (and the subdomain **should** look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRSQg.png)

Appreciate any help you guys can give.

Comment: Did you add a virtualhost in your http.conf ? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: We use WHM & cPanel on the server so the vhost creation is handled by cPanel. I have just checked via SSH and the vhost has definitely been created.

Answer (score 0):

if you get 403 try to look at apache log files. mostly you have wrong path or missing "/" or you are pointing to a wrong server (domain or development server).

Comment: I have checked the logs for the subdomain and there is nothing pertaining to the 403 errors.

Comment: Then your request goes to the wrong server. Try do use wireshark or a browseraddon like firebug to trace down the request. Seems you are sending it to another  server or the root domain.